# Regex match numbers of at least 6 digits that only have up to 3 digits different from 0

Tags: regex, oracle12c

**EDIT**

I need to identify all numbers of at least 6 digits and maximum 25 digits having only 1 to 3 digits that are different from 0.

Examples: 000123, 0103040000, 10320000, 70000000, 12000009000

I was trying something like this:

```
regexp_like(number, '[1-9]\d{1,3}') AND regexp_like(number,'(0){5,24}')
```

(it's ok to use more than one regular expression)

But this also matches numbers like:

0046700000031,00394000007 - This should not match because they have 4 digits other than 0, it must match numbers with minimum 1 digit other than 0 and maximum 3 digits other than 0

I'm using Oracle 12C.

**SOLUTION**

Here is an alternative I've found, which seems to work but I presume only in Oracle.

```
SELECT NUMBER
FROM TABLE t
WHERE LENGTH(NUMBER) > 5 HAVING(regexp_count(NUMBER, '0') > 2
      AND regexp_count(NUMBER, '[1-9]') BETWEEN 1 AND 3)
GROUP BY NUMBER
```

Thanks

Comment: what programming language / environment are you working in?

Comment: `000123` and `0103040000` also have `0` in the first 3 places. What exactly is it you want to match?

Comment: Does your DBMS support regex with `like`? Usually, it is either an operator like `~` or `REGEXP`, or `REGEXP_LIKE` / `RLIKE`.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Please, explain why `0046700000031` and `00394000007` should not match. Is it because of the leading 0s? They have 3 non-zero numbers. Please, bring some "should match/should not match" examples on the answer.

Comment: By the way, it really helps if you tell us which database you are using from the very start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a single regex to do what you want in Oracle 12C, because the regex engine is POSIX based, and does not allow lookarounds, neither lookbehinds, nor lookaheads. You need to use a single pattern to check the format of the string, and a regular `LENGTH` function.

Here is a full demo:

```
WITH testdata(txt) AS (
      SELECT '000123'        from dual
      UNION
      SELECT '0103040000'    from dual
      UNION
      SELECT '10320000'      from dual
      UNION
      SELECT '70000000'      from dual
      UNION
      SELECT '12000009000'   from dual
      UNION
      SELECT '0046700000031' from dual
      UNION
      SELECT '00394000007'   from dual
   )
   SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(txt, '^(0*[1-9]){1,3}0*$') AND LENGTH(txt) > 5 AND LENGTH(txt) < 26
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQQzuC/1/). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(0*[1-9]){1,3}` - one, two or three repetitions of

  - `0*` - zero or more zeros
  - `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
- `0*` - 0+ zeros
- `$` - end of string.

See the [Oracle demo online](https://rextester.com/BHSJ76444).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I also found an alternative meanwhile, which I'm going to post in the description above

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a positive lookahead to check for at least one, but no more than three, non zero digits:

```
^(?=.*[1-9])(?!.*[1-9].*[1-9].*[1-9].*[1-9])[0-9]{6,25}$
```

In a database such as Postgres, we could try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE number ~ '^(?=.*[1-9])(?!.*[1-9].*[1-9].*[1-9].*[1-9])[0-9]{6,25}$';
```

Using a database like SQL Server which does not directly support regex, but has some regex `LIKE` capability, we could try:

```
WHERE LEN(number) BETWEEN 6 AND 25 AND             -- 6 to 25 digits
      number LIKE '%[1-9]%' AND                    -- at least 1 non zero digit
      number NOT LIKE '%[1-9]%[1-9]%[1-9]%[1-9]%'  -- at most 3 non zero digits
      number NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%';                  -- all numbers
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated my answer, sorry, I missed that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern `(?=^([123456789]*0){1,3}[123456789]*$)\d{6,25}`.

Explanation: it uses lookahead to varify that what follows contains at most three zeros with pattern: `(?=^([123456789]*0){1,3}[123456789]*$)`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QyTv7c/1)